# Android SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When upgrading the app, i  am reading the data from db and moving data to new Db.

On the DBClass constructor, calling getReadableDatabase to call oncreate\onupgrade.

I am getting exception

### android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Post the full stacktrace and related code.

Comment: i dont have full stacktrace, we get this from google console

Comment: it is crashing on the DB constructor, on calling this method getReadableDatabase().

Comment: post your code atleast, if you are not able to see stacktrace